# how to do a scatter plot with empty circles in Vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I draw a  2d scatter plot with vtk, however points are full circles.
I would like to know how to do a scatter plot with empty circles please ?
I use this example for draw my scatterplot http://www.itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Plotting/ScatterPlot

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's not possible, at least not yet. I presume you're using vtk 5.10